# Haskell Inferred instance declaration on inherited classes

Tags: haskell

I've seen cases of chains of Haskell classes that all "extend" each other (see for example, the widget/container/etc classes in gtk2hs)

```
class Class1 a where....
class (Class1 a)=>Class2 a where....
class (Class2 a)=>Class3 a where....
....and so on....
```

where all the class functions have default values that depend on one Class1 function.  This works great, but makes for a really ugly "instantiation" of ClassN

```
Instance Class1 Object where
    func x = ....
Instance Class2 Object
Instance Class3 Object
Instance Class4 Object
Instance Class5 Object
....and so on....
```

(I've seen code just like this in popular hackage libraries, so I'm pretty sure that at the time of the writing of the code this was a proper way to do this).

My question- Are there any newer GHC extensions that would clean this up.  I've looked a bit and haven't found any.  Ideally, all you really need is to decleare Object as an instance of ClassN, and give the Class1 function, the rest would be inferred.

[preemptive snarky comment :)- This indicates an "object oriented" way of thinking, you should really learn how to program functionally.

My response- I agree it is very object oriented, but code like this exists in the ecosystem today, and might very well be needed, GUI libs like gtk2hs, for example.  From a practical viewpoint I need to write code like this sometimes, and I just want to simplify it.]

Comment: Trying to understand your question: are you wanting something that would allow you to declare `Object` as an instance of `Class1` and have it automatically figure out that it has an instance for `Class2` through `Class5`?

Comment: I am open to ideas, but I think it would have to go the other way around....  If you declare something an instance of Class1, there is no reason that it would have to be a ClassN (think of the Widet example, declaring something a Widget doesn't make it a Button, but the other way around is required).  Of course the ugly thing is that  you have to define a Class1 function in a ClassN instance.

Comment: I daresay this was never, by anybody, considered "a proper way". It's just that when you make bindings to an OO library, and want to translate the hierarchies more or less faithfully, you have to put up with some less-than-nice looking code.

Comment: @leftaroundabout- I agree, I feel dirty myself about this, but my preemptive snarky comment was to keep on track to get some practical advice on how to deal with something messy....  I'll bite a bit and make a comment anyway....  I've heard the argument before that gtk2hs is an OO wrapper, and the resulting code isn't ideal.  I get it, except one thing.... What is the perfect function GUI lib?  Ultimately you have a bunch of semi-interchangeable widgets that fall into a hierarchy, which I believe is inherently OO.

Comment: @jamshidh So if `Class1..N` all have distinct methods, how would you expect to get around this? If the `Button` typeclass has stuff that talk about what happens when pushed and the `Widget` typeclass talks about names and parents, there isn't a way to jump from one to the other

Comment: @jozefg- In certain cases this could be a problem, but in the case of gtk2hs not.  All the specific functionality is handled outside of the class mechanism, using separate attribute and signal types (which apply to only widgets of the correct class types).  The class hierarchy really does look like I showed above.  Like all tools, certainly an "instance inference" wouldn't be very useful in all cases, but would just what is needed in other cases.

Comment: It's pretty uncommon to have empty instances like that in my experience. If this is necessary in gtk2hs, it is to ease interoperability with the C library. I know you kind of mentioned this, but I feel it's important to emphasis that what Haskell calls a "class" is very different from the OO definition of the word "class" and it seems like you might be confusing the two somewhat. Additionally, what you are calling "objects" in your question are very different from the OO definition of "objects" and are actually types here. Also, Haskell doesn't really have a way to express subtyping.

Comment: @DavidYoung- They aren't actually empty, but rather the functions are all defined in terms of others so you only need to define one.  I come back to my question though....  What would a good Haskell GUI library written from scratch look like?  You would need some common properties to act on all widgets (position, width, height), and some common properties to describe just the containers (childWidgets), etc.  Ultimately this would form an inheritance tree, similar to OO.  Many people keep telling me that this is a bad way to do things, but what is the alternative?

Comment: @jamshidh- Functional reactive programming would probably be the way to go, but it has not fully matured yet. You can find examples of FRP libraries here: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_Reactive_Programming. Also, sum types can replace some kinds of subtyping. For example, instead of a `Button` class with instances, you could have a `Button` data definition that has constructors that allow you to make different kinds of constructors (probably very general constructors in the actual data definition and then actual functions that make more specific buttons).

Comment: @DavidYoung- I researched a bunch of these libs a while ago, and all FRP libs are based on another GUI widget lib (gtk2hs, wxHaskell, threepenny, etc) which themselves are OO-like.  I am actually writing an FRP lib myself right now (hence the question), and am facing the same problem....  how OO like should the underlying GUI lib be.  So far, unfortunately, the answer it "a lot" (I don't like this fact, mind you).

Comment: @DavidYoung- One thing that I feel strongly about is that a widget data structure should be open ended expandable (anyone real programmer who has programmed in HTML with its closed widget set would have to agree....  It is like programming in a language without definable functions).  Unfortunately data defines closed types.

Comment: @jamshidh- Like I said the data constructor could be very general. It could store a function that is used to create a button in some way and there could be other functions that you can compose to make new kinds of buttons. You may still need some typeclasses but maybe not as many. It doesn't need to be OO just because it's based on an underlying OO implementation, just as the OO implementation doesn't need to be procedular even if ultimately works with procedures. So the exposed interface doesn't necessarily need to be influenced by the design of the underlying implementation at all.

Comment: It isn't a matter of generality, but of extendability.  I want to supply predefined widgets to a user (like "button"), yet allow them to define their own (like "airplaneContolPanel").  Using "data" just shuts down this possibility, period.  I will hide anything low level I can, but the problems occur with functions that are needed by the programmer (like "widget position" or "widiget size", which a user will need to modify).  These functions fall into a class hiararchy, I can't get around that.  I would like to, but I can't.  I really should post a new question to discuss this....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42546/discussion-between-david-young-and-jamshidh)

Answer (score 3):

It is a discussed **proposal** to add Synonym Instances.

For example it would be possible to write next code:

```
type Stringy a = (Read a, Show a)

instance Stringy a where
     read = ...
     show = ...
```

in this case it would be possible to declare

```
type ClassAll a = (Class1 a, Class2 a, Class3 a, Class4 a)

instance ClassAll a where
   foo = ...
```

But for now, type constraint could be used in function's signatures only, not in instances.

**UPDATED**

As Vittor mentions, you can find proposal here: [Multi-headed instance declarations](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/DefaultSuperclassInstances#Multi-headedinstancedeclarations)
The original proposal is a part of [class aliases](http://repetae.net/recent/out/classalias.html) proposal

Comment: Your karma is 998 :)  I could be the guy who puts you over 1000 :)  Do you have a reference to this?  I found http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html, but the TypeSynonymInstances described there seems to be something else....

Comment: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/DefaultSuperclassInstances#Multi-headedinstancedeclarations
here is described the modern vision of extension.
http://repetae.net/recent/out/classalias.html - 
original proposal

Comment: Thanks....  I upvoted wit's answer, but already have missed my opportunity to be the only to put him over 1000 :) (I may still mark this as the accepted answer after my head wraps around this whole question).